# ForeignKey in Room Database

Tags: android, database, android-room

I am working on a structure where there are several articles and its content stored in two different tables

First is Articles table which contains its basic info as below :

```
@Entity(tableName = "Articles")
public class ArticleModel implements Serializable {

    @SerializedName("iArticleID")
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    public int articleId;

    @ColumnInfo(name = "disciplineId")
    public long disciplineID;

    @SerializedName("tTitle")
    @ColumnInfo(name = "tTitle")
    public String title;

    @SerializedName("file_path")
    @ColumnInfo(name = "article_path")
    public String articlePath;

    @ColumnInfo(name = "lastUpdated")
    public String lastUpdated;

    @ColumnInfo(name = "articleDescription")
    public String articleDescription;

    @ColumnInfo(name = "is_favorite")
    public String isFav = "false";

}
```

Second table is FileData which holds the content (file data) of that article as below

```
@Entity(foreignKeys = @ForeignKey(entity = FileData.class,
        parentColumns = "article_id",
        childColumns = "iArticleID",
        onDelete = CASCADE))
public class FileData implements Serializable {

    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    private int fileId;

    @ColumnInfo(name = "file_name")
    private String fileName;

    @ColumnInfo(name = "file_path")
    private String filePath;

    @ColumnInfo(name = "content")
    private String content;

    @ColumnInfo(name = "article_id")
    public int aId;

}
```

I want to perform an Inner Join query which provides me FilesData with some of the columns from Articles as well (For ex: is_favorite) 
For that, I tried to relate both tables with article_id using the ForeignKey constraint as mentioned in FilesData table.

Here is the third @Embedded class

```
public class FilesWithArticlesData {

    @Embedded
    ArticleModel articleModel;

    @Embedded
    public FilesData files;

}
```

and the inner join query is as below:

```
 @Query("SELECT FilesData.fileId, FilesData.file_name, FilesData.file_path, FilesData.content,articles.is_favorite FROM files" +
            " INNER JOIN ARTICLES ON articles.articleId = FilesData.article_id  " +
            "WHERE FilesData.content LIKE :searchText")
    public LiveData<List<FilesWithArticlesData>> searchContent(String searchText);
```

Whenever I try to run the app, I get error

```
error: (iArticleID) referenced in the foreign key does not exists in the Entity. Available column names:fileId, file_name, file_path, content, article_id
```

or **FOREIGN KEY constraint failed**

Any suggestions..??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**you have entered wrong parentColumn**

Just Change this

```
@Entity(foreignKeys = @ForeignKey(entity = ArticleModel.class,
        parentColumns = "iArticleID",
        childColumns = "article_id",
        onDelete = CASCADE))
```

instead of

```
@Entity(foreignKeys = @ForeignKey(entity = FileData.class,
        parentColumns = "article_id",
        childColumns = "iArticleID",
        onDelete = CASCADE))
```

And also change this

```
 @SerializedName("iArticleID")
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    public int articleId;
```

To this

```
 @ColumnInfo(name = "iArticleID")
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    public int articleId;
```

Comment: App crashing with error : 
io.reactivex.exceptions.UndeliverableException: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConstraintException: FOREIGN KEY constraint failed (code 787 SQLITE_CONSTRAINT_FOREIGNKEY)

Comment: Changed the foreign key datatype to Integer and worked..!!